# Laravel collection->diff() not working when using select

Tags: laravel, collections

I have table where I want to find difference in certain columns. I'm doing it with diff():

```
$inventoryitems1 = InventoryItem::where('inventory_id', $request->get('inventory1'))
    ->select('owner_id', 'location_id', 'asset_id')
    ->get();
$inventoryitems2 = InventoryItem::where('inventory_id', $request->get('inventory2'))
    ->select('owner_id', 'location_id', 'asset_id')
    ->get();
$difference = $inventoryitems2->diff($inventoryitems1);
```

And then i get empty array. But if I don't have select in my collection. It work, it shows all different rows. Is there anyother way to do this or this one is right but I'm not doing it the right way?

**UPDATE**
I have $inventoryitems1 collection that looks like this:

```
0: {asset_id: 2, owner_id: 2, location_id: 1}
1: {asset_id: 3, owner_id: 2, location_id: 1}
```

and $inventoryitems1 collection that looks like this:

```
0: {asset_id: 2, owner_id: 2, location_id: 1}
1: {asset_id: 3, owner_id: 6, location_id: 1}
```

I'm trying to find differences in those two collections, where we can see that **owner_id** is different in second collection. How can I only get those objects where there was some change (difference).

Comment: What are you more precisely trying to achieve? Calling `diff()` on the first collection just returns the objects that are not present in the second collection as well. When selecting only these three attributes, it compares them only, meaning that all of the unique combinations of owner, location and asset from the first collection are present in the second as well. When removing the select clause, you're leaving other properties as well, which are different, so you get results.

Comment: I'm trying to find changes that were made between two inventories. First and second collections are same only owner_id is changed and some other columns, but I only need changes for specific columns, like owner_id, location_id and asset_id other changes are not important.

Comment: I can't understand the whole concept. I'd suggest you provide some more code and background elaborations plus the difference between the expected outcome and what you're getting.

Comment: @D.Petrov I posted update, so you can check it out, if it's still not clear just let me know.

Comment: So you only want `1: {asset_id: 3, owner_id: 2, location_id: 1}` returned from the first collection or do you want the same returned from the second collection (hence with the changes)?

Comment: I want only the one with changes. this one `1: {asset_id: 3, owner_id: 6, location_id: 1}`

Comment: Hm, odd. I did some debugging myself and what you presented seems to be working just fine with my models when using select clause and the diff() method. You may alternatively try recreating its functionality manually with something like:
    `$filtered = $inventoryitems2->filter(function($item) use($inventoryitems1){
        return $inventoryitems1->every(function($item2) use ($item){
            return $item2 != $item; //or you can manually compare the three attributes, could also be the problem
        });
    });`